# What is the "convincible" birth story of the Lord Ganesha?

Tags: shiva, ganesha

I have heared from somewhere that Lord Ganesha was created from the feculence/ turmeric  of Goddess Parvati' body while bathing for protection of herself. Is it true? if yes, how is it really possible ? Also, then how Lord Shiva is considered as the father of  Lord Ganesha?

So can anybody tell me "convincible" birth story of the Lord Ganesha for clarifying above doubt ?

Comment: These 2 articles might help: http://bawandinesh.blogspot.in/2008/09/ganeshji.html
http://bawandinesh.name/the-secret-of-lord-ganesha-i-2/

Comment: You can't find a single story for birth of Ganesha.. Because Lord Ganesha manifests himself in different ways in different kalpas... Thus there are different stories...

Comment: When Shiva beheaded Ganesha, Shiva transformed his male energy via Trishul to Ganesha. Thus this kid is both son of Parvati (Prakriti) and Shiva (Purusha). Similarly, Shiva's seed (Purusha) travelled all this nature and was carried by different Goddess. Indeed Goddess and nature represents Adis Shakti or Amba and thus Kartikeya is son of both Shiva and Shakti.

Comment: Parvati did not make him from feculence. She made him from turmeric of her body.

Comment: @Sree how is it possible?

Comment: This is a folktale which has a symbolic meaning, forgotten by nearly everyone. Lord Ganesha was created by Siva as the first being, Ekadanta. The story about being created from Parvati's body is to convey the idea that Ganesha has the qualities of both mother and father. There is more to the symbolism, but I don't know the depth of it.

Comment: See answer of @Tezz ,

Comment: Destriyer and Tezz are right